# searching files with grep and only outputting parts of lines

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I'm looking though log files and trying to get a less cluttered output in my end file.  If I grep for a value I want to then format the output to remove anything but the date and the url.

For example here is a line of the file.

> ***Sep 25 08:07:51*** 10.20.30.40 FF_STUFF[]: 1545324890 1 55.44.33.22 10.9.8.7 - 10.60.154.41 **http://website.com** 0 BYF ALLOWED CLEAN  2 1 0 0 0 (-) 0 - 0 - 0 sqm.microsoft.com - [-]   sqm.microsoft.com - - 0

I want to do a grep, or a better command if necessary, to output to a .txt file with only the bold entries listed. Basically list date and URL.  So how do I tell it to list the first 15 characters including spaces, then find the first http/https and list everything until the first empty space?  Each line is not the same length or anything of that nature so I can not just go by character position.

So my output would be

> Sep 25 08:07:51 http://website.com

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To supplement @randomir's answer, we can also use `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\{15\}\).*\(https\?:\/\/[^ ]\+\).*/\1 \2/' < input.txt > output.txt
```

This pattern assumes that the first 15 characters composes the date and that the URL contains no spaces. It works for both *http* and *https* URLs.

---

**Edit** - to address the comment—for the sake of learning, we can also invoke `sed` to perform line-matching operations like `grep`:

```
sed -n '/10\.45\.19\.151/p' < input.txt
```

...will output any lines in *input.txt* that contain the IP address `10.45.19.151`. The `-n` option suppresses output of every line. We combine this option with the *`p`* command to *print* only lines that match the pattern.

We can merge this approach with the first command to "grep" for lines *and* transform them using a single command:

```
sed -n '/<line-match-pattern>/ s/<...>/<...>/ p' < input.txt
```

...will select only the lines that match `<line-match-pattern>`, perform the substitution, and output the result. To illustrate, here's an example using the information provided in the comment:

```
sed -n '/10\.45\.19\.151/ s/\(.\{15\}\).*\(https\?:\/\/[^ ]\+\).*/\1 \2/ p' \
    < messages-20171001 \
    > /backup/mikesanders-fwlog-10012017.txt
```

Comment: Excellent!  I'm first searching the master log for an IP address then piping that to your command to filter out the extraneous data.                         grep 10.45.19.151 messages-20171001 | sed 's/\(.\{15\}\).*\(https\?:\/\/[^ ]\+\).*/\1 \2/' > /backup/mikesanders-fwlog-10012017.txt

Comment: @Aaron_W , as a bonus, we can also use `sed` in place of `grep`. I updated the answer to show how with one command.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily use `-o` option in `grep` because you have two patterns, separated by a variable number of characters (and `-o` will print the complete matched part).

If you wanted to extract only URLs, this would suffice:

```
$ grep -oE 'https?:[^ ]+' file
http://website.com
```

But to extract both the date and the URL, probably the simplest solution is with **GNU `awk`**:

```
$ awk '{ match($0, /https?:[^ ]+/, url); print $1, $2, $3, url[0]; }' file
Sep 25 08:07:51 http://website.com
```

where you print first three fields (`$1` to `$3`, space-separated), then search for a URL with [`match()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-match-regexp-in-string) (assuming it contains no spaces, i.e. that space characters are always properly escaped; either as `+`, or `%20`), and then print the first URL found (after the date).

In case you have **POSIX `awk`** (or call `gawk` with `--posix` flag), the solution is a little bit more verbose, since POSIX `match()` doesn't support saving of the matched parts into an array (third argument, `url`) and you'll have to explicitly extract URL with [`substr()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-substring) when a match is found:

```
$ awk '{ match($0, /https?:[^ ]+/); print $1, $2, $3, substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); }' file
Sep 25 08:07:51 http://website.com
```

Comment: Note that the use of an array as the third argument of `match()` is a GAWK-ism, and does not work in traditional awk. RavinderSingh13 had the right idea by using RSTART,RLENGTH, though his regex needs work.

Comment: @ghoti, thanks for the heads up. I forgot to note the solution was for `gawk` only. Fixed.

Comment: One thing, when I do a search of a single /var/log/messages I get exactly what I'm looking for.  but when I do a search of all the messages files since it archives them weekly, I get additional data in the front of the date on the print out.  For example if I run that on /var/log/messages* I get output of "messages:Oct 1 04:05:47 http://website"  why is it adding in "messages" on the front?

Comment: @Aaron_W, `grep` adds the name of the file in front, when run on multiple files. To suppress that default behaviour, run it with the `-h`/`--no-filename` option.

Comment: @Aaron_W, also, you can avoid using `grep` altogether and do the IP filtering in `awk` (f.e. `awk '/8\.8\.8\.8/ { ... }' files`).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{match($0,/http[^com]*/);print $1,$2,$3,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+3)}'  Input_file
```

**Explanation of above code:**

```
awk '{
match($0,/http[^com]*/);                  ##Using match default utility of awk where I am searching for regex where it will look for string http till string com comes.
print $1,$2,$3,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+3)##Now printing the 1st, 2nd and 3rd column which are date and time in current line and printing sub string of current line where it should start substring from the value of RSTART till value of RLENGTH(which will be http complete URL actually). Now point to be noted here variables RSTART and RLENGTH are default variables of awk which will be set once a regex match is found in match utility of awk.
}
' Input_file                              ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Rather than making your answer a request, why not make it an answer? If this is how you recommend the OP solves his problem, then just include your code, along with an explanation of what it's doing and why it's better than other alternatives. One-liners are great, but consider also splitting it out into a multi-line program that includes comments. Our purpose here is to educate, not just to make life difficult for consultants who actually get paid for this stuff.

Comment: @ghoti, I apologies sir, my only intention is to learn and help people. I usually add explanation to code, let me add it here. Also it is my habbit to write could you please, will work on it now, apologies again.

Comment: No apologies necessary. We're all learning here, both to code and to communicate more effectively. This is a reasonable solution, just not yet a great answer.

Comment: @ghoti, I added explanation now and removed the requesting line in my answer, kindly do let me know if any more changes are needed, will be more than happy to edit, thanks again.

Comment: What is `/http[^com]*/`? It seems unlikely to me that it's doing what you think you want it to do. For example, try this: `echo "http://www.example.com/foo" | grep -Eo 'http[^com]*'`. Since fields are separated by single spaces, I suspect the regex you want `https?://[^ ]+` (escaped appropriately of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -o` to match each of the line sections that you want, then reassemble the lines that grep returns:

```
$ grep -Eo '^.{15}|https?://[^ ]+' f | paste - -
Sep 25 08:07:51 http://website.com
```

Note that in FreeBSD or OSX, the old version of GNU grep they use (2.5.1) is buggy, so more explicit date recognition is in order:

```
$ grep -Eo '[A-Z][a-z]{2} ([0-9]{2}[ :]){3}[0-9]{2}|https?://[^ ]+' f | paste - -
Sep 25 08:07:51 http://website.com
```

A workaround in FreeBSD is to use `bsdgrep`, which is functionally equivalent to gnu grep but without the bugs. In MacOS, one might need to install an alternative using homebrew or macports .. or just use the POSIX awk solution in another answer.

Anyway, in both cases, the regular expression consists of two expressions joined with an or-bar (`|`, before `https`). The first subexpression matches your dates, the second one matches your URLs.

As long as *every* line of input contains text that match both of these elements, you should get two lines of output from grep for each log entry. Then `paste` reassembles them into a single line.

Comment: Clever trick, but very fragile -- unless you have a firm guarantee that each and every line contains both the date and the URL (which usually, when parsing logs, you don't).

Comment: @randomir Very true. As it happens, every line in the sample set in the question seems to work with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just 1 command line like:

`msr -p my.log -t "^(.*?\d+:\d+:\d+).*?(https?://\S+).*" -o '$1 $2' -PIC > output.txt`

- If `first 15 characters` is more reliable than pattern `"^(.*?\d+:\d+:\d+)"`:

  Use `"^(.{15})"` like: `-t "^(.{15}).*?(https?://\S+).*"`
- If you want to further filter like containing one ip `10.9.8.7` as a plaint-text(`-x`):

  `msr -p my.log -x 10.9.8.7 -t "^(.*?\d+:\d+:\d+).*?(https?://\S+).*" -o '$1 $2'`
- If must contain more IPs like `10.9.8.7` `10.9.8.8` `10.9.8.9`, or further processing:

  `msr -p my.log -t "^(.*?\d+:\d+:\d+).*?(https?://\S+).*" -o '$1 $2' -PAC | msr -t "10\.9\.8\.[7-9]" -PAC > output.txt`

`msr.exe`/`msr.gcc*` is a [single exe tool](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/tree/master/tools) for such ETL alike work (Load -> Extract -> Transform or Replace file) [in my open project](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/README.md), about 1.6MB, no dependencies, with cross platform versions plus `x86`/`x64` versions.

- **Load** files recursively (`-r`) and filter directory name, file name, time, size like:

  `-r -p dir1,dirN,file1,fileN  -f "\.(log|txt)$" --w1 2017-09-25` and `--nf "excluded-files"` `--nd "excluded-directories"`, `--s1 1.5MB` `--s2 30MB`, `--w2 "2017-09-30 22:30:50"` etc.
- **Extract** by **general** `Regex` unlike `sed` or `awk`, exactly same as `C++`/`C#`/`Java`/`Scala`/etc.:

  `-t "^(.*?\d+:\d+:\d+).*?(https?://\S+).*"` ignore case: add `-i` like: `-i -t` or `-it`
- **Transform** output like:

  - `-o '$1 $2'` for Linux or `Cygwin`/`Powershell` on Windows.
  - `-o "$1 $2"` for Windows `CMD console window` or `*.bat`/`*.cmd` files.

See following screenshot:
[image: Extract log and transform output]

If you're on Linux, you can just run `msr.gcc48` or `msr-i386.gcc48` it's 32-bit machine. Just run the exe you'll get the usages and examples, or see online docs about [performance comparison](https://github.com/qualiu/msr/blob/master/perf/summary-full-Cygwin-comparison.md) (with Linux system tool **grep** and Windows system tool **findstr**), built-in docs like: [msr on CentOS](https://qualiu.github.io/msr/usage-by-running/msr-CentOS-7.html), colorful [vivid demo on Windows](https://qualiu.github.io/msr/demo/windows-test.html).